# SMTP.starttls() got an unexpected keyword argument 'keyfile' with django 3.2.23 and python 3.12.1

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to configure my web app to send confirmation emails after registration. I'm using Django 3.2.23 and Python 3.12.1 and my settings are :

```
    if 'DEVELOPMENT' in os.environ:
        EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
        DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'boutiqueado@example.com'
    else:
        EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
        EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
        EMAIL_PORT = 587
        EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
        EMAIL_HOST_USER = os.environ.get('EMAIL_HOST_USER')
        EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = os.environ.get('EMAIL_HOST_PASS')
        DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = os.environ.get('EMAIL_HOST_USER').
```

I'm having this error message :
TypeError at /accounts/signup/
SMTP.starttls() got an unexpected keyword argument 'keyfile'
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    https://boutique-ado-mike-8ab1d2bb405e.herokuapp.com/accounts/signup/
Django Version: 3.2.23
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:
SMTP.starttls() got an unexpected keyword argument 'keyfile'
Exception Location: /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py, line 67, in open
Python Executable:  /app/.heroku/python/bin/python
Python Version: 3.12.1
Python Path:
['/app/.heroku/python/bin',
'/app',
'/app/.heroku/python/lib/python312.zip',
'/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.12',
'/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.12/lib-dynload',
'/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages']
Server time:    Thu, 14 Dec 2023 09:57:01 +0000

I checked the EMAIL_HOST_USER and EMAIL_HOST_PASS and both are ok. The pass provided by gmail had spaces but I removed the spaces in the pass. The app is in production and all the vars are in heroku config vars. How can I solve this. I tryed to change EMAIL_USE_TLS = True to EMAIL_USE_SSL = True and port to 465 but the error persists. help please!!!

Comment: Solved using touch runtime.txt && echo "python-3.9.16" > runtime.txt

Comment: Django 3.2 is not compatible with Python 3.11. See also https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/34118